# Rails: Allow users only to get points only once. (Prevent users from refreshing page and get points again)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a course system in rails and I want to award users points for completing a certain task but I want to avoid that the users can refresh the page and get the points again.

My controller looks like this:

```
def beginnerscourse_08c
   @user = current_user
   @completion = "100%"
   @user.increment(:tradepoints,  100)
   @user.save
end
```

What is the easiest way to make a boolean or similar system that checks if the user was already awarded theses points and if not reward them.

Comment: What models do you have in your application?

Comment: From the code it looks you are have a column `tradepoints` in the Users table

Comment: Are you using devise gem `current_user`

Comment: I am not not using devise. Yes I have the colum tradepoints in the table. I have the model User in my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an association table that has `user_id` and `course_id` columns as foreign keys. The purpose of the table is to keep track of which users have received awards for which courses. For example:

```
user_id    course_id
   1           1
   2           1
   2           2
   3           1
   4           3
```

Looking at the above table you can clearly see that User 1 has completed Course 1, User 2 has completed Course 1 and 2, and so on. You can then check that table to see if a specific user has received awards for the given course before incrementing their points, as well as do things like show the user a list of courses they have completed, or run reports on how many users have completed a given course.

Comment: Oh this makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: So this would mean I would create a courses table. And as soon as the user starts a course I would say that the course belongs to a user and a user has many courses right.

Comment: I would create it as `course_completions` and add the record when a user completes a course, but only if an identical record doesn't already exist (i.e. they haven't completed it before). Other details depend on the rest of your application.